# Is it possible to write a read-only property of an enumerator?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class `Seat` with an enumerator of type `SeatType` with the enum values `Window`, `Aisle`, and `Middle` as follows:

```
public enum SeatType
{
Window,
Aisle,
Middle
}
```

Is it possible to use an enumerator like a property? I was attempting to make a way to assign a seat object's `SeatType` usable based on reading another variable as follows, but I am unsure this is the right way to return a seat type `SeatType` based upon a given seat letter `_seatLetter`. I was attempting to make it so that if the `_seatLetter` instance variable of an object is a certain character then the object's enumerator is either `Window`, `Aisle`, or `Middle`.

```
public enum Type
{
  get 
  { 
    if (_seatLetter == 'A' or _seatLetter == 'F')
    {
      return SeatType.Window;
    }
    else if (_seatLetter == 'C' or _seatLetter == 'D')
    {
      return SeatType.Aisle;
    }
    else
    {
      return SeatType.Middle;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a *switch* statement

Comment: The problem I am having is that I am unsure how to set a ```Seat``` object's ```SeatType``` as a certain enum based upon a ```Seat``` object's ```_seatLetter```

Comment: An enumeration only provides values, no logic. All logic contained in an enum is the fixed corellation between a number and a value (string)(`public enum SeatType { Window = 1, ...`). If you want a logical correlation between i.e. `SeatType` and a seat letter, you'll need a method, property or a class

Comment: Your property should start with `public SeatType Type`. Other than that, it should work.

Comment: There is also no `or` operator in C#

Comment: you can use enum as a property. it is like using an int as a property but instead of seeing a number like 0, you see "Window". enum properties can be set or read (get). in your case the enum property will just return something, but cannot be set. Though it is somehow implicitly set by setting _seatLetter somewhere else in your class. For example in the constructor of the Seat class. you could implement a setter for this enum property, then when you set the enum property it will set _seatLetter for you. _seatLetter is the so called "backing field" in this case.

Comment: An enumerator is not an enum. These are two different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, but if the name of the property is Type and the return type SeatType it's correct, but you must change a bit the declaration of the property:

```
public SeatType Type
{
    get 
    { 
        if (_seatLetter == 'A' || _seatLetter == 'F')
        {
            return SeatType.Window;
        }
        else if (_seatLetter == 'C' || _seatLetter == 'D')
        {
            return SeatType.Aisle;
        }
        else
        {
            return SeatType.Middle;
        }
    }
}
```

or as switch:

```
public SeatType Type
{
    get 
    { 
        switch (_seatLetter)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'F':
                return SeatType.Window;
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
                return SeatType.Aisle;
            default:
                return SeatType.Middle;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use many approaches depending on your starting situation, that we don't know.

This is a possible approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Seat seat = new Seat('A');
    }
}

public class Seat
{
    public SeatType Type { get; set; }

    public Seat(char seatLetter)
    {
        SetSeatType(seatLetter);
    }

    public void SetSeatType(char seatLetter)
    {
        switch (seatLetter)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'F':
                Type = SeatType.Window;
                break;
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
                Type = SeatType.Aisle;
                break;
            default:
                Type = SeatType.Middle;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum SeatType
{
    Window,
    Aisle,
    Middle
}
```